# Get random numbers that sum to a value N and have a specific variance

Tags: variance, random-variable, random-generation

As the title says, I need numbers that sum to a value N lets say 0.9 and have a specific variance. My background is not in mathematics so please be gentle with the terms.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the trivial step of converting variance to standard deviation (by taking the square root) and sum to mean (by dividing by the number of observations), this is already answered on site. The basic idea would be to simulate any data you like from some continuous distribution, standardize it to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1, then multiply by the required standard deviation and add the required mean.

Comment: If the linked duplicate doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to clearly distinguish it from what is given in answers there.